# Implementing unit of work in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, autofac

I have implemented unit of work in the next way in Entity Framework Core.

Context:

```
public class DaleContext : DbContext, IDaleContext
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringProvider _connectionStringProvider;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionStringProvider.ConnectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DaleContext(IConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider)
    {
        _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
    }
    
    public DbSet<ProductProducts { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x =x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task<intCommitAsync()
    {
        return await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity: IDisposable, IRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork as UnitOfWork;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork.DbContext.Dispose();
    } 

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _unitOfWork.DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
}
```

I have injected all with autofac:

```
public static class Container
{
    public static ContainerBuilder RegisterInfraestructure(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();

        return containerBuilder;
    }
}

public static class Container
{
    public static ContainerBuilder RegisterDataResources(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        containerBuilder.Register(x =new ConnectionStringProvider(configuration.GetConnectionString("Fgcm.Dale"))
        ).As<IConnectionStringProvider>();

        containerBuilder.RegisterType<DaleContext>().As<DbContext>().As<IDaleContext>();

        return containerBuilder;
    }
} 

public static class Container
{
    public static ContainerBuilder RegisterRepository(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>().As<IProductRepository>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<SaleDetailRepository>().As<ISaleDetailRepository>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<SaleRepository>().As<ISaleRepository>();
        
        containerBuilder.RegisterDataResources();
        containerBuilder.RegisterInfraestructure();

        return containerBuilder;
    }
}

public static class Container
{
    public static ContainerBuilder RegisterApplicationServiceResources(this ContainerBuilder
    containerBuilder)
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterRepository();

        containerBuilder.RegisterType<DaleApplicationService>().As<IDaleApplicationService>();

        return containerBuilder;
    }
}
```

When I try to save data it doesn't works (doesn't insert data) ... I would like to know why ? Here are when I try to save:

```
    public Product Create(Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            _productRepository.Create(product);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
            return product;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And of course all are injected:

```
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
    private readonly ISaleDetailRepository _saleDetailRepository;
    private readonly ISaleRepository _saleRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public DaleApplicationService(IProductRepository productRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository,
        ISaleRepository saleRepository, ISaleDetailRepository saleDetailRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _saleRepository = saleRepository;
        _saleDetailRepository = saleDetailRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

What am I missing?

PS: all this works with .NET Core Web Api.

Comment: Are you sure that di scopes are good?

Comment: Please try to only post the relevant code. Too much code is just obscuring your question. Besides, writing "When I try to save data it doesn't works" doesn't really explain what you are experiencing. What error are you getting? Where exactly are things going wrong? If you can point to a specific line in the code that's even better.

Comment: @zolty13 I think that yes ... But how to track that ???

Comment: @Xerillio updated

Comment: `"I have implemented unit of work in the next way in entity framework core:"` ← Why? The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: Try not catching the exception then doing nothing with it...

Comment: @Igor Do you have an implementation of this ? I mean with for example with services application layer and meadiatr ??? You mean that unit of work and repository pattern is an antipattern ???

Comment: @FreddyCastelblancoMacias - What I mean is that these patterns are already implemented in the out of the box Entity Framework objects (DbContext = UoW, DbSet = Repository). There is no need to try to create your own custom wrapper around those existing implementations (Repository around a Repository and a UoW around a UoW). Do not do that, you are shooting yourself in the foot and making it difficult for anyone that has to work with your code.

Comment: I see the other comments and typically my approach was to do the same thing that the OP is doing.  Microsoft has improved entity framework so that we don't need to do this anymore.  Unless you are using Dapper for example instead of entity framework, the repository pattern is a now-defunct pattern if you are working with entity framework because you can better mock EF.  See here: https://garywoodfine.com/generic-repository-pattern-net-core/.  Although, I do think there is value in using only what you need if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zolty13 sort of hinted the [Instance scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-scope) of your `DbContext` (`DaleContext`) is probably incorrect. By default Autofac sets the instance scope to [Instance per dependency](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-dependency) (also known as a "transient" lifetime) which means a new instance of `DaleContext` is created for every class that depend on it. So your `UnitOfWork` receives a different instance of `DaleContext` than `IProductRepository`. So changes in `IProductRepository` are not reflected in `UnitOfWork`.

One way to solve this is to avoid this convoluted wrapping of your DbContext like @Igor suggest. Do you really need this `UnitOfWork`? Instead, use a repository class that has **one** instance of `DaleContext` and make all the DB changes in there and save them.

Alternatively (if you really think you need a `UnitOfWork`) you can register your `DaleContext` with an [instance per request](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request) scope. Do note: Entity Framework's DbContext is **not** thread safe, so if you need to do concurrent work, this is not a safe approach.

Otherwise, read up on [Instance scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-scope).